# Fixing a series of loose sentences: Strunk & White

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Rule 18 of Strunk & White talks about avoiding a succession of loose sentences. It gives the following example for a bad construction:

> The third concert of the subscription series was given last evening,
>   and a large audience was in attendance. Mr. Edward Appleton was the
>   soloist, and the Boston Symphony Orchestra furnished the instrumental
>   music. The former showed himself to be an artist of first rank, while
>   the latter proved itself fully deserving of its high reputation. The
>   interest aroused by the series has been very gratifying to the
>   Committee, and it is planned to give a similar series annually
>   hereafter. The fourth concert will be given on Tuesday, May 10, when
>   an equally attractive program will be presented.

What will be a good way to rewrite the above by avoiding loose sentences? I tried the following:

> The third concert of the subscription series was given last evening.
>   The concert was attended by a large audience. Mr. Edward Appleton was
>   the soloist, supported by Boston Symphyony Orchestra on instruments.
>   Mr. Edward Appleton showed himself to be an artist of first
>   rank, at the same time, Boston Symphony Orchestra too proved itself
>   of deserving its high reputation.
>   Gratified by the interest shown, the Committee has
>   planned to give a similar annual series hereafter. The fourth concert
>   will be given on Tuesday, May 10, with an equally attractive program.

Comment: Remember that Strunk & White's "rules" are largely the opinions of Messrs. Strunk and White. They greatly oversimplify what constitutes good writing, and slavish devotion to "the rules" can have the opposite effect, making it awkward and unnatural. That may be why no one has responded thus far.

Comment: There is no way to definitively answer this question. Appropriate rewrites are a matter of opinion.

Comment: Strunk and White don't even follow their own "rules" in their own writing. Don't feel like you need to either.

Comment: Let's update this to contemporary English: "#Appleton rocked it at #BSO last night.  Full house.  Committee will continue series next year.  See you May 10 for no 4!" ;)

Comment: Merk, you had me at # ;-)

Comment: **Mod notice:** Your bounty was refunded to allow the migration to [writers.SE]—however, the migration was rejected [per their policy](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a stab at it:

A large audience attended the third concert of the subscription series last evening. Mr. Edward Appleton, a proven soloist of first rank, was supported by the Boston Symphony Orchestra which again proved itself fully deserving of its high reputation. The Committee is gratified with the interest in their series, and has planned similar annual performances hereafter. The fourth concert of the series will be given on Tuesday, May 10 with an equally attractive program.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what Strunk and White mean by "loose sentences," but the paragraph certainly uses the passive voice too much! By using the active voice, I've been able to convey the same meaning with about 40 fewer words. The word count for the original version is about 98; for my version, about 58.

> The Boston Symphony, joined by soloist Edward Appleton, gave a well attended third concert in the subscription series last night. Mr. Appleton proved to be a first-rank artist, and the orchestra lived up to its high reputation. The Committee has been gratified by increased audience interest, and its future plans include offering this series annually. The orchestra's fourth and equally attractive concert takes place on Tuesday, May 10.

Comment: They were complaining that all the sentences in the paragraph had very similar structures; you've fixed it by getting rid of some of the passive constructions. (Although if the entire concert was played by the BSO, I wouldn't say *performed at*; I'd say *gave*).

Comment: @PeterShor: Yeah, I too prefer "gave." Thank you! Don

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt.  I've taken out all but one of [the constructions Strunk and White object to](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html#14) (namely, sentences joined in the middle with "and", "while", "when" etc) and changed the sentence order a little for clarity, but I haven't rewritten it completely as modern English.

My reordering removed the need for the usage of "former" and "latter", which, while correct English, tend to increase the complexity of a piece of writing and hence put more cognitive load on the reader as they skip backwards to check which was which.

---

The third concert of the subscription series attracted a large audience last evening.

The Boston Symphony Orchestra furnished the instrumental music, proving itself fully deserving of its high reputation, while the soloist, Mr. Edward Appleton, showed himself to be an artist of first rank.

The fourth concert on Tuesday, May 10 will feature an equally attractive program. The Committee is very gratified by the interest this series has aroused, and plans to give a similar series annually hereafter.

Comment: HDB, interesting that we both moved the 'date' sentence to before the plan to make the concert an annual event.  The original sentence order was a confusing read.

Answer (score 0):

Last evening, the Committee held their third subscription series 
concert with a well-attended performance featuring soloist,  Mr. Edward Appleton and the instrumental music of the Boston Symphony Orchestra.

Artist, Mr. Edward Appleton exemplified a first-rank performer, and the Boston Symphony Orchestra's high reputation was left unblemished.  An equally enticing fourth concert program will be presented on Tuesday, May 10.

The Committee is gratified with the interest in their series, and hereafter have planned similar annual performances.

Comment: *"exemplified a first-rank performer"*?  How is this better than *"Edward Appleton showed himself to be an artist of first rank"*?

Comment: Because "showed himself" does not describe his talent as directly as does the term 'exemplified'.  Could the soloist have shown his talent without the exemplification?  'Showed himself' is appropriate when it stands alone -no further action or if Mr. Edward Appleton's talent did not require a performance to prove this description.                                                                                                    Further, an example where 'showed himself' should not be edited from "showed himself" to 'exemplified': "Jesus showed himself again to the disciples..."

Comment: Strunk and White were containing about boring sentence structure in that passage, not about a deficit of grandiloquent words.